# Can I pass the element I'm hovering on as an argument to my function when using @mouseover='' in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to accomplish the following thing - I have an image element with an alt tag that contains the string `TEST`. I'm trying to make it so that when a user hovers over that image, he'd get an absolutely positioned box underneath the image that will contain what is inside the alt tag of the image. While I'm not completely sure how to do this I've begun trying things out which may or may not work.

Right now my idea is this - on `@mouseover` event, I will pass the hovered element as an argument to a function which will get the dimensions of the image tag, create an element and position it underneath the image element using position: absolute;

The problem is that I'm not sure if I can actually pass the specific element that I'm hovering on using @mouseover as an argument to my function.

I'm also curious if this is a good way to do what I'm trying to do or are there better ways. I'm open to suggestions. Thanks for reading.

Template

```
<img @mouseover='displayAlt(element)' src="#" alt="TEST">
```

Script

```
methods: {
    displayAlt(element){
        let alt = element.alt
        // Rest of the stuff will go here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following to implicitely pass the event object to the method. `alt` can be found on the `target` property of the event object:

```
<img @mouseover='displayAlt' src="#" alt="TEST" />

methods: {
    displayAlt(e){
        let alt = e.target.alt
        // Rest of the stuff will go here
    }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/fb8yoamw/1/) in action.

Otherwise you can explicitly pass the event object using the special variable `$event`. From the [Vue.js - Event Handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) docs:

> Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline
> statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special
> $event variable

```
<img @mouseover='displayAlt($event)' src="#" alt="TEST" />
```